# Is reference to this safe to use in a class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
class Obj
{
private:
    Obj& self{*this};
    // now use self for . notation and this for -> notation
public:
}
```

Are there any disadvantages to this kind of usage, or is it simply a bad idea to have 'self' as an option to use within your class?

Comment: what is it you are trying to accomplish? inside the class you have this, outside the class instance you have the object itself.

Comment: `this` only exists inside non-static member functions.

Comment: When you copy the class, the `self` of the new object will reference the original instance, not the new one.

Comment: And what is the original problem you try to solve with something like that? If it's just plain curiosity, then that's fine but please [edit] your question to state it. Otherwise this is really an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice try to use [other languages syntax](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/400875/209774).  But no, it's not safe:

```
class Obj
{
private:
    Obj& self{*this};
    // now use self for . notation and this for -> notation
public:
    void test() { cout<< (this==&self?"ok":"nok")<<endl; }
}; // semicolon, please

int main() {
    Obj o; 
    o.test(); 
    Obj o2{o};
    o2.test();   // OUCH!!!
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/lhvtQg)

Making it safe using the [rule of 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) is possible but cumbersome and error prone. Better accept to use to use `this` and embrace C++ idioms ;-)

By the way, in a member function, you do not need to use `this->member_variable` or `this->member_function(...)` unless you have some ambiguity.  So `self.member_variable` or `self.member_function(...)` is of no advantage: use the much simpler form of  `member_variable` or `member_function(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to take care of copy constructor. You don't define any constructors for class Obj, thus the compiler will automatically generate a copy constructor as public member of Obj class, which copies every member variables, in your case is private member variable "self", and performs no other action. (see details in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

You need to define copy constructor to avoid auto generated one to do copy on "self". Something like this:

```
class Obj
{
private:
    Obj& self{*this};
    // now use self for . notation and this for -> notation
public:
    Obj() {} //user-defined constructor
    Obj(const Obj&) {} //user-defined copy constructor
}
```